# HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable in php file

Tags: php, wamp

how can i solve this error.
`file_get_contents(http://www.example.com/name/j/92801): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable in line`
Here is php file code.
`echo $file = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/name/j/92801");`
I am using wamp server 2.4

Comment: Is this any help http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17300/what-are-the-causes-of-a-416-error

Comment: I can not find the solution here.

Comment: Well that seemed to suggest that the issue was in example.com and not your site/code or maybe in a cache

Comment: how can i get the content is there any way

Comment: change `www.example.com` with some REAL url :-)

Comment: I'm getting this error as well and would like to know if anyone find the solution at this problem?

Answer (score 1):

first of all is `allow_url_fopen` enabled on your php.ini file? and second of all its better to use CURL heres a little function to help you

```
function curl($url , $ua = FALSE){
            if($ua == false){
                $ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
            }
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_URL , $url);
            curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true);
            curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , true);
            curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_USERAGENT , $ua);
            return curl_exec($ch);
        }
```